# How to retrieve data from uploadID depends on userID who uploads the picture?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my recyclerview everytime the user uploads image it will post in feed. The user can click on image inside the feed. But the problem is i am getting the wrong data. I want to show there the description, uploader name etc. (See firebase database under 'uploads')

```
        mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("uploads/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("uploadID")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // ...
            for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                tvUserInfo.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue()));

                tvUserDesc.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("mName").getValue()));

            }
```

**Here where I putExtra on uploadID**

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Normal Click at position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), BookProfile.class)

            .putExtra("uid", mUploads.get(position).getUserId())
            .putExtra("imagengpost", mUploads.get(position).getmImageUrl())
            .putExtra("title", mUploads.get(position).getmName())
            .putExtra("desc", mUploads.get(position).getDesc())
            .putExtra("uploadID", uploadId);

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Testing uploadID : " + uploadId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    startActivity(intent);


}
```

**Firebase realtime database**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a listener to `/uploads/$uploadid`, so that listener reads the snapshot of a single upload. In that case the `snapshot` in `onDataChange` is for a single upload, so you don't need to loop over `snapshot.getChildren()`.

SoL

```
mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("uploads/" + getIntent().getStringExtra("uploadID")).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        tvUserInfo.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("desc").getValue()));
        tvUserDesc.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("mName").getValue()));
    }
```

---

Note that your code is also broken in the case where you **do** have multiple children, since you're accessing the `dataSnapshot` inside the loop, where you'd probably want `childSnapshot` in that case:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        tvUserInfo.setText(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("desc").getValue()));
        tvUserDesc.setText(String.valueOf(childSnapshot.child("mName").getValue()));
    }
```